# Вывести лабиринт в консоль

Tags: python, c++, c, консоль, ascii

Есть лабиринт, записанный в массиве.
Если `maze[i][j]` = 1, то это стена, иначе - проход.
У меня получилось вывести вот в таком формате:

```
██████████████████████
██                  ██
██  ██████████  ██  ██
██  ██          ██  ██
██████████  ██████  ██
██  ██      ██      ██
██  ██████  ██  ██  ██
██  ██      ██  ██  ██
██  ██  ██████  ██  ██
██      ██      ██  ██
██████████████████████
```

Но мне надо вывести это в ASCII символах, то есть:

```
 ━┳━━┳┓
┣╸┃┏━┛┃
┃╻╹┗┓╺┫
┃┗┓╻┗╸┃
┣╸┃┃╺━┫
┃╺╋┛╺━┫
┗━┻━━━
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Нужно смотреть соседние ячейки к каждой ячейке. Условно, каждой группе ячеек (3x3) на верхнем лабиринте соответствует один символ в нижнем. Группы при этом накладываются друг на друга. Нужно прописать соответствие групп символам, потом циклом идти по ячейкам верхнего лабиринта и их соседям, сопоставлять каждой ячейке (и ее соседям) соответствующий символ. Для удобства обработки я еще бы пустые колонки и строки со всех сторон лабиринта добавил.

Comment: Это не ASCII символы, а [псевдографика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Я не знаю как в питоне. Шаг 1 - определить или выставить нужную кодировку в консоли. Можно вывести таблицу - символ-код. Шаг 2 - если не получается выставить кодировку или найти нужные символы - задача решения не имеет ("кодовая страница" может не содержать символов псевдографики, 866 - точно есть псевдографика, 1251 - в ней нет этих сиволов, нет и всё). Шаг3 - берем коды символов и на их основе выводим их в консоль.

Comment: Вот таблица для 866 кодировки http://lybohna2005.narod.ru/Images/Uroki_ris/Informatika/1/cp866.gif как перевести код символа в символ - думаю можно найти. Если кодировка другая то не получится.

Comment: Проще работать со строками в utf8.  Можно указать кодировку исходника (файла python), и вставить символы как строковые константы, а не как коды символов.

Comment: @nick_n_a Зачем в 2023 году рекомендовать кому-то 866, тем более когда по ссылке выше все символы уже есть.

Comment: @user7860670 у вас есть опыт работы с консолью?

Comment: @nick_n_a ¿Зачем в 2023 году использовать режим 1251?

Comment: @nick_n_a современные ОС (в том числе и Windows) могут юникодные символы на консоль выводить. Можно обойтись без использования cp866, cp1251, достаточно знать юникодные коды соответствующих символов псевдографики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете массив из всех возможных символов. Их будет 2<sup>4</sup> = 16.

Индекс в массиве занимает 4 бита, и удобно расставить элементы так, чтобы каждый бит означал свой кусок стены - верхний, нижний, левый и правый. Например так:

```cpp
std::string arr[16] = {/*0000*/"·", /*0001*/"╹", /*0010*/"╻", /*0011*/"┃", /*0100*/"╸", /*0101*/"┛", ...};
```

Дальше, при рисовании лабиринта определяете индекс в массиве по наличию соседей.

```cpp
if (!cell[x][y])
    draw(" ");

int index = 0;
if (y > 0 && cell[x][y-1])
    index |= 1 << 0;
if (y < height-2 && cell[x][y+1])
    index |= 1 << 1;
// и т.д.

draw(arr[index]);
```